# How to convert \input{} to plain text?

Tags: input, qrcode

This is what I have (`a.txt` contains `http://www.google.com`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myurl{\input{a.txt}}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\begin{document}
\qrcode{\myurl}
\end{document}
```

Doesn't work. However, this one works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myurl{http://www.google.com}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\begin{document}
\qrcode{\myurl}
\end{document}
```

How can I convert what's coming from that `\input` to the plain text so that it doesn't confuse `qrcode`?

Comment: **(1)** Please provide a complete code and not just fragments. **(2)** What is the content of `a.txt`? **(3)** What are you trying to achieve in general (for example, I don't get the necessity of `\newcommand\blah{\input{a.txt}}`)?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I updated my question, thanks for corrections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primitive input command is expandable so most likely you can do

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{qrcode}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\everyeof{\noexpand}
\edef\blah{\@@input a.txt }
\makeatother

\qrcode{\blah}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use `catchfile`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.link}
http://www.google.com
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\CatchFileDef\myurl{\jobname.link}{\endlinechar=-1 }

\begin{document}

X\myurl X

\qrcode{\myurl}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I checked the QRcode and it contains the desired link. The usage of `filecontents` is just for making the example self-contained and not clobbering my files.